# Несколько окружностей вокруг круга

Tags: css, svg

Подскажите, как сделать несколько окружностей разного диаметра вокруг одного круга?
Тут нужно для каждой окружности применять отдельный блок со свойством border-radius?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы решал вопрос с помощью `svg`.

Comment: Да, обертка с position:relative, и внутри блоки для круга и окружностей с position:absolute; c border-radius: 100% каждый.

Answer (score 12):

Вариант с использованием `box-shadow`

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  margin: 38px;
  height: 345px;
  width: 345px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #000, 0 0 0 8px #F5F5F5, 
              0 0 0 16px #000, 0 0 0 18px #F5F5F5, 
              0 0 0 26px #000, 0 0 0 28px #F5F5F5, 
              0 0 0 36px #000, 0 0 0 38px #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вариант с фоном

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/04/11/21/painted-lady-1568926_960_720.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.b-circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.b-circle-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.b-circle-line:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -16px;
  left: -16px;
  right: -16px;
  bottom: -16px;
}

.b-circle-line:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: -24px;
  left: -24px;
  right: -24px;
  bottom: -24px;
}

.b-circle-line:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: -32px;
  left: -32px;
  right: -32px;
  bottom: -32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-circle">
  <span class="b-circle-line"></span>
  <span class="b-circle-line"></span>
  <span class="b-circle-line"></span>
  <span class="b-circle-line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать это же, но только фоном, т.е. чтобы за этой фигурой можно было поставить изображение?

Comment: @HamSter т.е. нужно убрать чёрный фон и оставить все круги

Comment: @Qwertiy, подскажите, как это сделать

Comment: @word - добавил

Answer (score 8):

Можно сделать с помощью `background`:

```css
div {
  height: 345px;
  width: 345px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 71%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 71%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 71%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 71%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 71%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 71%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: какие-то "погрызанные" круги

Answer (score 7):

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.style.background = 'black';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const radius = 100;
canvas.width = canvas.height = 2*radius;
const circle = r => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(radius, radius, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
for(let i = 0; i<7; i++) circle(radius - i*7);
ctx.fill();
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Answer (score 5):

### Вариант с SVG

Svg формат создан именно для того, чтобы рисовать фигуры в несколько символов.

```
<circle cx="0" r="80">
```

Плюс полная "отзывчивость" к изменению размера окна браузера.

```html
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="0 0 400 400"  
style="background:#000" >
<g transform="translate(85,85)" stroke-width="1" stroke="cyan" fill="none" >
   <circle cx="0" r="80"  />
   <circle cx="0" r="70" />
<circle cx="0" r="60" />
  <circle cx="0" r="50" />
    <circle cx="0" r="40" />    
</g>
</svg>
```

### SVG анимация

**UPD**  (Добавление вызвано комментарием @Qwertiy)

Анимация увеличения радиусов окружностей реализована с помощью изменения параметров команды `scale()` Но при увеличении коэффициента происходит пропорциональное увеличение и ширины линий окружностей.
Чтобы избежать этого нежелательного эффекта применяется свойство: `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

```html
  <svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%"  viewBox="0 0 288 288"  
style="background:#000" >
  
  <g transform="translate(144,144)"  stroke-width="2" stroke="cyan" fill="none" >
   <circle cx="0" r="128" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  >
<animateTransform 
      attributeType="xml" 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="scale" 
      values="1;0.2;1" 
      dur="9s" 
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
   </circle>
 <circle cx="0" r="64" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" >
<animateTransform 
      attributeType="xml" 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="scale" 
      values="1.2;0.4;1.2" 
      dur="5s" 
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
</circle>
<circle cx="0" r="32" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
<animateTransform 
      attributeType="xml" 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="scale" 
      values="1;2;1" 
      dur="5s" 
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
</circle>
<circle cx="0" r="16" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" >
<animateTransform 
      attributeType="xml" 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="scale" 
      values="0.6;1.2;0.6" 
      dur="3s" 
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
</circle> 
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: transform можно анимировать через css - будет кроссбраузерно и современно. Но стоит учитывать, что при изменении scale ширина линии тоже меняется.

Comment: @Qwertiy благодарю за ценный комментарий. Утолщение линий при увеличении scale(n) устранено с помощью `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

Answer (score 3):

Хм.. Похоже, радиальному градиенту добавление одного пикселя гладкости не добавляет, в отличие от линейного... Но всё равно оставлю так.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;

  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at 50% 50%,
    black       0%,
    black calc(45% - 1px),
    white      45%,
    white calc(45% + 3px),
    black calc(45% + 3px + 1px),
    black calc(55% - 1px),
    white      55%,
    white calc(55% + 3px),
    black calc(55% + 3px + 1px),
    black calc(65% - 1px),
    white      65%,
    white calc(65% + 3px),
    black calc(65% + 3px + 1px)
  );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```